# Error java.lang.Integer is not within bounds of type-variable T; BinarySearchTree

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree

I want to create a simple Binary Search Tree which uses generics to specify the data type.
However, when I want to create a new tree of Integers, I get the following error:

> type argument java.lang.Integer is not within bounds of type-variable T

I tried other data types which are clearly extending `Comparable`, so why is this not working?

Here is my code:

Interface:

```
public interface Comparable<T>
{
    int compareTo( T t );
}
```

BinarySearchTree:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
private T content;
private BinarySearchTree<T> leftChild, rightChild;

public BinarySearchTree()
{
    content = null;
    leftChild = null;
    rightChild = null;
}

public T getContent()     
{
    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        return content;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return content == null;
}

public boolean isLeaf()
{
    return !isEmpty() && leftChild.isEmpty() && rightChild.isEmpty();
}

public void add(T t)
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        content = t;
        leftChild = new BinarySearchTree<T>();
        rightChild = new BinarySearchTree<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        if(content.compareTo(t) > 0)
        {
            leftChild.add(t);
        }
        if(content.compareTo(t) < 0)
        {
            rightChild.add(t);
        }
    }
} 

public int size()
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1 + leftChild.size() + rightChild.size();
    }
}

public boolean contains(T t)
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(content.compareTo(t) > 0)
            leftChild.contains(t);
        else if(content.compareTo(t) < 0)
            rightChild.contains(t);
        return true;
    }
}

public void show()
{
    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        leftChild.show();
        System.out.println(content);
        rightChild.show();
    }
}

}
```

Main:

```
public class main
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    test();
}

public static void test()
{
    BinarySearchTree<Integer> tree = new BinarySearchTree<>();
    tree.add("5");
    tree.add("10");
    tree.add("3");
    tree.add("1");
    tree.show();
}
}
```

The error comes with this line: `BinarySearchTree<Integer> tree = new BinarySearchTree<>();`

Comment: Why are you adding Strings to a `BinarySearchTree<Integer>`?

Comment: That's a mistake I didn't fix yet, I used a String Tree before.

Comment: Just made a minimal example myself, and it compiles without any problem. If you really did define your own `Comparable`, then this is indeed exacrly the problem - `Integer` is-a `java.lang.Comparable<Integer>`, but you seem to expect it to be of your own `Comparable` type, and that is not true. It would've been if Java supported duck typing, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you've defined your own interface `Comparable<T>`, of which `Integer` is not a subtype.

Delete your `Comparable`, and use the one in `java.lang` instead.

Also, as Eran pointed out, you shouldn't be adding `String` values to a `BinarySearchTree<Integer>`.

Comment: Thank you! So, my own Interface was overriding the default one, is that what created the error?

Comment: Yes. It's generally a bad idea to create your own classes or interfaces with the same names as classes or interfaces in `java.lang`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create your own `Comparable` interface. It's a part JDK, you can use it.